# path for aws with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm setting up paperclip to save to S3 to persist all my attachments etc between deployments.

Unfortunately, it is saving the Images to a path dependent on the deployment:

```
http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/flexcareers/var/deploy/flexpertlinode/web_head/releases/20150828162423/public/redactor_rails/pictures/20/original_3066814584_0d0db6817c.jpg?1440779173
```

I've tried to avoid this by setting the path, in the default_options hash, and then in the initializer.  It doesn't make any difference to where the file is saved.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_host_name => 's3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
:path => "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],      
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
```

}

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get paperclip to save the files to S3 in a more predictable location.

Ideally, I would like to not fix this by setting the path in the model, as that will then change the behaviour in development environment, which doesn't use S3.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`add one more thing:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does link to the images successfully.  The issue is the path has the release number in it, which seems bad.  The images are displayed though and this didn't fix the path